# Unable to Unlock the drive using bitlocker windows 7

Tags: windows-7

When I tried to Unlock the drive using my password iam getting the following error

**"The system could not find the environment option that was entered"**

yesterday i was able to unlock it .but now i cant .The password is right.Please help me friends and experts,

Answer (score -1):

At this point I have the following suggestions for you.

A)     If you have another user account, try booting into that. If able to boot, run a system restore from there. You can also try running a system file checker scan from that account. This scans for system files that may have become corrupted and will attempt to repair/replace them.

NOTE: The command prompt should be opened with the admin privileges. To do that, Click on the Start button, then type in “cmd” in the “Start search” bar. Once the cmd icon appears on the start menu, right – click on the icon and from the drop down menu, choose the “Run as administrator” option. Then type in “SFC /scannow” and press “Enter” to start the scan process.

B)      Else, To repair your computer using Startup Repair follow these steps:

```
Boot into Vista installation DVD
Choose your language settings and click Next
Click Repair your computer
Choose your operating system and click “Next”. This should bring up System Recovery Options.
Click on Startup Repair
```

Startup Repair should now start diagnosing your system to identify the root cause of the failure. Once it has identified the root cause, it would automatically start repairing your computer. If you are curious to know what Startup Repair did, you can click on the details link and see which tests Startup Repair ran to diagnose the problem.

After Startup Repair has finished the repairs, click Finish to reboot your computer.

Your computer should now be able to boot normally into Vista!!

Note -- If your computer cannot boot into Vista even after repairs, then go back to System Recovery Options and run System Restore.